# hive broke after dropping a table

Tags: mysql, hive

I had installed hive 2.0.0 on my hadoop cluster using mysql as MetaStore. Hive works fine until yesterday when I tried dropping a table whose actual .orc file in HDFS had been deleted.

After that, hive suddenly broke. First, the hive command line hang for several minutes before giving the hive>  prompt. Second, if i type **show databases;** on hive command line, it would again hang for a long time and gave back errors all about **Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'hive'@'namenode01-bi-dev' (using password: YES)** 
I tried the following command posted on other question and got the same problem.

```
hive --service metastore
```

I had searched through stackoverflow about this error. Most post is about setting mysql privileges. However I don't think this is the case for my problem. I had checked several time on hive-site.xml and mysql that the user have the correct privileges. If it's the privilege problem , how can hive worked fine before dropping the table. Just in case,below are the  related hive-site.xml fields:

```
<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
 <value>hive</value>
 <description>password to use against metastore database</description>   
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://10.104.90.40:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
 <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
 <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
```

And in mysql :

```
mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host              | password                                  |
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost         | *CFBF6F2FB240D9B28DC5D0A313B6BAA047368AAF |
| root | namenode01-bi-dev |                                           |
| root | 127.0.0.1         |                                           |
|      | localhost         |                                           |
|      | namenode01-bi-dev |                                           |
| hive | localhost         | *4DF1D66463C18D44E3B001A8FB1BBFBEA13E27FC |
| hive | namenode01-bi-dev | *4DF1D66463C18D44E3B001A8FB1BBFBEA13E27FC |
| hive | datanode02-bi-dev | *4DF1D66463C18D44E3B001A8FB1BBFBEA13E27FC |
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show grants for hive@'namenode01-bi-dev'
-> ;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hive@namenode01-bi-dev                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hive'@'namenode01-bi-dev' IDENTIFIED BY     PASSWORD '*4DF1D66463C18D44E3B001A8FB1BBFBEA13E27FC' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hive`.* TO 'hive'@'namenode01-bi-dev'                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I had tried reinstall mysql and hive on namenode and reboot the machine but encounter the same problem. Currently, I am using a datanode to run the mysql server and hive .With exactly the same setting and configuration, hive on datanode works. But I still can't figure out what went wrong for hive on namenode. The error just doesn't make any sense.Had anyone encounter the same problem or know what went wrong?

Comment: Did you search the logs of MySQL service, Metastore service, HiveServer2 service? This kind of authentication error could result from any kind of failure,from a network timeout to a zombie process to a corrupt file...

Comment: I checked mysql log and it's all about common info like innodb started.Though i tried setting log-warnings ＝2 but the mysql log still doesn't contain info about access attempt. The hiveserver2 log has the same error messange mentiond on the question.

Comment: So what about the *Metastore* service, that sits between the database itself and the applications (i.e. HS2 service, legacy Hive CLI, Pig CLI, Sqoop CLI, Spark driver, Impala daemons, Presto daemons, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, the problem indeed relate to the Metastore. It's causing from one of the setting on hive-site.xml as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: It turned out that the hive-site.xml is not the root cause. The root cause is mysql refusing metastore connection though the priviliges were set in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this problem is caused by mysql.
After adding the following line into /etc/my.cnf, hive works fine as before

```
skip-name-resolve
```